# Getting html from fetch request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to get the html from an api response. If I execute the following fetch request:

```
const fetchHtml = () => {
  return fetch('local:8080/api/getHtml')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response:");
      console.log(response.text());
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Data:");
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
};
```

I get the following console message:

```
Response:
Promise {<pending>}
  __proto__: Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]]: "<html><head><title>Your interest in PROGRAM_NAME</ `Show 108 096 more Copy`"
Data:
undefined
```

How do I get the returned html promise value from my fetch api request? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to return response.text from .then

```js
const fetchHtml = () => {
  return fetch('local:8080/api/getHtml')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    }).then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    });
  };
};
```